# Using a separate class for toolbar functions in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

Lets say I have two different activities, both using the same toolbar, making use of the same layout and menu options. This part is no problem.

If I want a menu option to execute a specific function, I would naturally create a function, `foo()`, and call it when the menu option is selected. Because the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method i handled individually in each acitivity, would it be a good practice to use a separate class with static "toolbar functions"? E.g. having a `logout()` function accessible from the dropdown menu in the toolbar from any activity.

It may seem obvious, however, I cannot find any "best practices" on the matter. So what are the best practice(s) for handling multiple activities calling the same "toolbar function"?

Example code: lets say `MainActivity` and `SecondActivity` both have the same toolbar. In both `onCreate()` methods:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Somewhere else in both of the acitivites:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item_foo:
            ToolbarFunctions.foo(); //Is this a good way to do it?
        default:
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: another one who sees no difference between `android` and `android studio`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good practice it's using main parent activity class and extend all other activities. Here is some example of your parent Activity:

```
public abstract class MyParentActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

// This is your abstract function for other activity!
public void foo();

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item_foo:
            foo(); //Is this a good way to do it? Yes, here it's okey!
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

So you can define 10 your activity that extends from MyParentActivity as a code below. That is all:

```
public class MyOtherActivity extends MyParentActivity {

   // Here your function will be called in every time
   // when you click to Toolbar buttons! 
   //
   // And you don't need write again about clicking menu!

   @Ovveride
   public void foo () {

   //Any your behaviour

   }

}
```

Comment: Nice. So I take it if I want a single one of my activities to have an extra option in the menu, I would then overwrite the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method?Or should I create a separate toolbar for that activity?

Comment: @blae yes, than you can just override methods which you want, for special behavior...

Answer (score 0):

You can define a BaseActivity class and extend all other activities from the BaseActivity. You would include the common parts in the BaseActivity.

Answer (score 0):

If your foo() function has only logic and no view logic, then is better to keep it in static class.It will be faster and unit testable. If it has view logic in it than go with BaseActivity example. If it has view and functional logic together may be is better to be static and also extend BaseActivity which must implement an interface with a method for your view updates.That interface you will pass to you static foo() method which will do the functional logic and will return with the interface to the activity called it, to let the activity update the view it self. Than you can still unit test your foo() method.

```
public interface FooInterface{
    void onFooDone(Foo foo);
}

public static void foo(FooInterface fooInterface){
 calculate...
  if(fooInterface!=null)
    fooInterface.onFooDone(fooObject);
}
```

Your activity must implement FooInterface
and call foo(this);